# C# DynamoDB Query a nested property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, amazon-web-services, nested, amazon-dynamodb

I've the `MyTableItem` class that maps a DynamoDB table.
I need to implements the `GetMyTableItemsWithoutFinalStatus` method that query the table by specific filters on nested property of a custom type, `MyStatus`.

The filter has to check if:

- there's no status
- status is not initialized
- there's no "final" status in the status list
- date is greater than today - daysFromNow

So my conditions in OR are:

- StatusCount == 0
- Status == null
- **Status.Where(s => s.Status != StatusEnum.DELIVERED).Count == 0**
- Date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-daysFromNow)

Actually I need to get back all the items that has no status or no final status, because I've to update them.

How can I implement the condition on nested property of `MyStatus` object?

This is my code

```
[Serializable]
public class MyTableItem
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // My complex object
    [DynamoDBProperty(typeof(MyStatusConverter))]
    public MyStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public int StatusCount { get { return Status.Count; } set { value = Status.Count; } }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyStatus : IList<MyState>
{
    private readonly IList<MyState> stateList = new List<MyState>();

    public PeppolDespatchAdviceState this[int index]
    {
        get { return stateList[index]; }
        set { stateList.Insert(index, value); }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return stateList.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return stateList.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    // IList interface implementation...    
}

[Serializable]
public class MyState
{
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string SkipCause { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public enum StatusEnum
{
    DEFAULT,
    CREATED,
    DELIVERED,
    UNDELIVERABLE,
    RE_RECEIVED
}

#region Converter definition

public class MyStatusConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

    public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

#endregion

public IList<MyTableItem> GetMyTableItemsWithoutFinalStatus(long id, int daysFromNow = 3)
{
    try
    {
        List<MyTableItem> items = new List<MyTableItem>();
        DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig();
        operationConfig.OverrideTableName = "MyTableName";
        operationConfig.IndexName = "MyIndex";

        List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        conditions.Add(new ScanCondition(MyTableItemTableAttributes.StatusCount, ScanOperator.Equal, 0));
        conditions.Add(new ScanCondition(MyTableItemTableAttributes.Status, ScanOperator.IsNull));
        // Here I need to add a LINQ condition: Status.Where(s => s.Status != StatusEnum.DELIVERED).Count == 0 )
        conditions.Add(new ScanCondition(MyTableItemTableAttributes.Date, ScanOperator.GreaterThan, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-daysFromNow)));
        operationConfig.QueryFilter = conditions;
        operationConfig.ConditionalOperator = ConditionalOperatorValues.Or;

        DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(DynamoDBClient);
        items = context.Query<MyTableItem>(id, operationConfig).ToList();

        return items;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```